# SQL Agent with an infinite WMI loop package

Tags: ssis

I created a Job to run a SSIS package on a startup.  When I start the job at step it shows..

"Start job" - Success
"Execute job" - In progress...

The package starts and runs but the job hangs like that.

The only thing I can think of is that it's an infinite WMI loop and the job is waiting for the package to complete but it never should since it is a loop.

Has anyone had success running looping packages?

Comment: Could you better explain the flow and the tasks involved ?

Comment: Its a WMI Query that watches a folder for a file drop.  This is contained within an infinite for loop. Once the file is detected it runs a data flow and writes the information to a table in my DB and then continues the process over again to wait for another file.

Comment: Arte you using variables to pass information to the cycle? if you don't add more detailed information on the structure I can not understand where the problems are..

Comment: So I wrote a simple package.  Infinite For loop where true == true.  Inside that for loop is a WMI event watcher thats using a variable "SELECT * FROM __INSTANCECREATIONEVENT Within 30 where targetinstance ISA \"CIM_DataFile\"
 AND TargetInstance.Drive = \"C:\"
AND TargetInstance.Path = \"\\\\SSIS Source\\\\\"
AND TargetInstance.FileName like \"timesheet_report%\" AND TargetInstance.Extension = \"csv\""  Thats it